# Getting error in deploying my application in Google Application Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am able to run my code in local.

I am under a proxy. Without setting the http proxy, I got **[Errno 10060]**. It was rectified, once the proxy was set.

Now I am getting the below error. Can anyone please advise?

```
C:\Data\Google\google_appengine>appcfg.py update c:\Data\Exercises\helloworld

Application: helloirshi; version: 1

Host: appengine.google.com

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Data\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 125, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())

  File "C:\Data\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 121, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)

  File "C:\Data\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line4072, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)

  File "C:\Data\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line4063, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()

  File "C:\Data\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line2547, in Run
    self.action(self)

  File "C:\Data\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line3820, in __call__
    return method()

  File "C:\Data\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line3015, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)

  File "C:\Data\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line2997, in UpdateVersion
    updatecheck.CheckForUpdates()

  File "C:\Data\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line593, in CheckForUpdates
    runtime=self.config.runtime)

  File "C:\Data\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 366, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)

  File "C:\Data\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)

  File "C:\Data\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)

  File "C:\Data\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "C:\Data\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)

  File "C:\Data\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 354, in do_open
    req)

  File "C:\Data\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1174, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)

  File "C:\Data\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 958, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)

  File "C:\Data\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)

  File "C:\Data\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)

  File "C:\Data\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)

  File "C:\Data\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()

  File "C:\Data\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 151, in connect
    self._tunnel()

  File "C:\Data\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 99, in _tunnel
    (_, code, message) = response._read_status()

  File "C:\Data\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Sorry for my Grammar..

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happen if you try to skip updates with --skip_sdk_update_check ?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error.  Make sure your application settings are correct (Edit -> Application Settings).

In particular, ensure the port is something valid (like 8080).  Also set the server to appengine.google.com.